# Why if a set is equal to its dual, then its complementary is $L^2$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{[n]}$ be an *increasing* set of subets of $[n]$, i.e., if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \subset B \subset [n]$ then $B \in \mathcal{A}$. We also say that $\mathcal{A}$ is *decreasing* if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \subset A \subset [n]$ then $B \in \mathcal{A}$

Define the *dual* of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}^* = \{A \subset [n] : [n]-A \notin \mathcal{A}\}$and the *complement* of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}^c = \{B \subset [n] : B \notin \mathcal{A}\}$.

We also say that $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{[n]}$ is $L^s$ ($s=2,3,\dots$) if $A_1  \cup \dots  \cup A_s \neq [n]$, for all $A_1,\dots, A_s \in \mathcal{A}$

Prove that:

1. if $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}^*$, then $\mathcal{A}^c$ is $L^2$.
2. if $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}^*$, then $\mathcal{A}^c$ is not $L^3$.

I've proved that if $\mathcal{A}$ is increasing, then $\mathcal{A}^*$ is also increasing and $\mathcal{A}^c$ is decreasing. I've also proved [1], but I don't know how to prove [2].

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I'm very confused: your definition of $L^s$ doesn't actually use $s$ anywhere in it. Do you mean that the union over any $s$ sets is not equal to $[n]$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It was a typo, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: @Lecter In the definition of 'dual', do you want $[n]-A \in \mathcal{A}$ rather than $[n]-A \not \in \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 No, no. It's defined like that: $[n]-A \notin \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) is false. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A \in [n] : 1 \in A\}$. Then $$\mathcal{A}^* = \{B \in [n] : [n]\setminus B \not \in \mathcal{A}\} = \{B \in [n] : [n] \setminus B \not \ni 1\} = \{B \in [n] : 1 \in B\} = \mathcal{A}.$$ However, $\mathcal{A}^c = \{A \in [n] : 1 \not \in A\}$ is $L^3$: for any $A_1,A_2,A_3 \in \mathcal{A}^c$, $1 \not \in A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$ and thus $A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \not = [n]$.

Comment: It's correct. Now I realised that one statement was missing (drawn in red). What would happen now?

Comment: @Lecter You ask a new question. If you send me the link to the new question, I will think about it. I already spent time on this question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601331/why-if-a-set-is-equal-to-its-dual-then-its-complementary-is-not-l3

Comment: @Lecter My answer was off by a bit. I just fixed it.

Comment: Yes, but the complementary of the complementary is itself the collection. So I got the idea of your answer.