# Why if a set is equal to its dual, then its complementary is not L3.

Tags: combinatorics

This question comes from a typo in the bountied question [Complement is $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597760/why-if-a-set-is-equal-to-its-dual-then-its-complementary-is-l2).

Let $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{[n]}$ be an *increasing* set of subets of $[n]$, i.e., if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \subset B \subset [n]$ then $B \in \mathcal{A}$. We also say that $\mathcal{A}$ is *decreasing* if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \subset A \subset [n]$ then $B \in \mathcal{A}$

Define the *dual* of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}^* = \{A \subset [n] : [n]-A \notin \mathcal{A}\}$and the *complement* of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}^c = \{B \subset [n] : B \notin \mathcal{A}\}$.

We also say that $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{[n]}$ is $L^s$ ($s=2,3,\dots$) if $A_1  \cup \dots  \cup A_s \neq [n]$, for all $A_1,\dots, A_s \in \mathcal{A}$

Prove that if $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}^*$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is increasing, then $\mathcal{A}^c$ is not $L^3$.

I've proved that if $\mathcal{A}$ is increasing, then $\mathcal{A}^*$ is also increasing and $\mathcal{A}^c$ is decreasing. But I don't know how to prove the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A \in [n] : 1 \in A\}$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is increasing and $$\mathcal{A}^* = \{B \in [n] : [n]\setminus B \not \in \mathcal{A}\} = \{B \in [n] : [n] \setminus B \not \ni 1\} = \{B \in [n] : 1 \in B\} = \mathcal{A}.$$ However, $\mathcal{A}^c = \{A \in [n] : 1 \not \in A\}$ is $L^3$: for any $A_1,A_2,A_3 \in \mathcal{A}^c$, $1 \not \in A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$ and thus $A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \not = [n]$.

Comment: Nice! So Seems that sometimes is $L^3$ and sometimes is not. Depending of your choosing of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Lecter It's the same exact example btw

Comment: Yes yes, I posted the question before seeing your previous' answer correction.